# Скрипт на сканирование файлов и папок

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Нашел шаблон с php скриптом который считывает в корне сайта папку files.

Сайт лежит у меня по пути `/var/www/web/`, т.е скрипт считывает только папку `/var/www/web/files`. Как переписать в скрипте путь чтобы он мог сканировать файлы с папки `/Z/FTP/`?

Вот сам скрипт и откуда я взял шаблон если кому иитересно http://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/

```
<?php

$dir = "files";

// Run the recursive function 

$response = scan($dir);


// This function scans the files folder recursively, and builds a large array

function scan($dir){

$files = array();

// Is there actually such a folder/file?

if(file_exists($dir)){

    foreach(scandir($dir) as $f) {

        if(!$f || $f[0] == '.') {
            continue; // Ignore hidden files
        }

        if(is_dir($dir . '/' . $f)) {

            // The path is a folder

            $files[] = array(
                "name" => $f,
                "type" => "folder",
                "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
                "items" => scan($dir . '/' . $f) // Recursively get the contents of the folder
            );
        }

        else {

            // It is a file

            $files[] = array(
                "name" => $f,
                "type" => "file",
                "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
                "size" => filesize($dir . '/' . $f) // Gets the size of this file
            );
        }
    }

}

return $files;
}



// Output the directory listing as JSON

 header('Content-type: application/json');

 echo json_encode(array(
"name" => "files",
"type" => "folder",
"path" => $dir,
"items" => $response
 ));
```

Comment: какой то странный вопрос, вы новичок? $dir = $GET['dir']; dir - переменная содержащая путь к каталогу, и еще ван надо настроить сервер на доступ к нужным каталогам

Comment: Да ни разу не работал с php. $dir = $GET['dir'] вот так не работает. А если сделать так $dir = "/Z/FTP/"; то файлы не отображает, но поиск по файлам работает.

Comment: вам только эта директория нужна? какой код ответа сервера приходит? возможно просто у группы пользователей нету прав на чтение этой директории, тут надо открывать права на чтение в ОС и на сервере

Comment: и да правильно писать $_GET, сам уже года три php не трогал. читайте как с ним работать если вам нужна не только эта директория

Comment: права на папку стоят на  "Z" dr-xr-xr-x  11 nobody nogroup на "FTP" "drwxrwxrwx 10 nobody  nogroup

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, следует поменять третью строку с

```
$dir = "files";
```

на

```
$dir = "/Z/FTP";
```

и пятую снизу строку с

```
"name" => "files",
```

на

```
"name" => "FTP",
```